# Facebook Graph API search returning strange results

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**UPDATE: This was Facebook's internal bug, it is fixed.**

I'm trying to get events from places that are around a specified location (currently testing only with Birmingham, UK). When I use facebook graph sdk to search for places with parameters center={lat},{lng}&distance=1600 (around 1 mile), in the first page of it's results everything looks fine, except there is one result from India, how is that possible?

```
$places = $fb->get("/search?type=place&center={$search[0]},{$search[1]}&fields=id,name,location,cover.fields(id,source),events.fields(id,event_times,is_canceled,ticket_uri,type,name,cover.fields(id,source),picture.type(large),description,start_time,end_time,attending_count,declined_count,maybe_count,noreply_count).order(chronological).since({$currentTimeStamp})&distance={$radius}", $access_token);
```

All results return their location with latitude and longitude, and all of them are close to each other, but there is only one result "Salt Lake City, India", that has completely different location from Birmingham...

Can anyone explain this to me?

**EDIT**
Example on FB Graph Explorer
[example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplace%26center%3D52.48624299999999%2C-1.890401%26fields%3Did%2Cname%2Clocation%2Ccover.fields(id%2Csource)%2Cevents.fields(id%2Cowner.fields(id%2Cname%2Cemails)%2Cevent_times%2Cis_canceled%2Cticket_uri%2Ctype%2Cname%2Ccover.fields(id%2Csource)%2Cpicture.type(large)%2Cdescription%2Cstart_time%2Cend_time%2Cattending_count%2Cdeclined_count%2Cmaybe_count%2Cnoreply_count).order(chronological).since(1509460162)%26distance%3D1600&version=v2.10). For me, it shows one of the results to be from India, but it should only show from Birmingham.

Comment: Not gonna go dig out appropriate lat/long now, please prepare an example request in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: I have provided a link to example on graph explorer. You would just need to provide access token as it requires user access token to get event. @CBroe

Comment: Looking at the lat/long for that location, that clearly looks like a bug - suggest you go report it here, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: @CBroe Ok, will do that. Thank you for your time anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi this is an open bug already reported.
You can follow it here: [Graph API Search for places gives results outside of distance radius](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1964040817254857/)